# Java : How to implement stateful webservice calls by REST?

Tags: web-services, rest, stateful

I'm implementing a web service by RESTFul API.

**How to make the same instance available to many webservice calls, and keep in memory the new status of this instance?**

Let's consider we have an object **Obj1** (having as attributes **Id** and **Rank**) and many webservice calls : **call1** for method **increment()**, **call2** for method **getRankeValue()**...

Let's suppose that **(Obj1.Rank==0) was equal to true**, and let's suppose that **call1** has done **Obj1.Rank++**.

How can we make **call2** say that **(Obj1.Rank==1) was equal to true**?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method that generates a unique token and use in all other method calls, so the server can keep track of state.